# Ionic-native NativeStorage doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I'm trying to retrieve a key from Ionic-Native's NativeStorage on Android. I am able to retrieve data from storage on iOS, but on Android, calls to NativeStorage result in an exception.

I normally set and g data from the data store as shown:

```
$cordovaNativeStorage.setItem('test', 'value').then(
    function(){
        console.log('successfully set item');
        $cordovaNativeStorage.getItem('test', 'value').then(
            function(result){
                console.log('Set item and got it back. Value is' + result);
            }, function(){
                console.log('Set item but could not get it back')
            });
    }, function(){
        console.log('could not set item at all');
    });
```

However, when I try to set data to storage (or get it back), I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
at Object.get (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8100/lib/ionic-native/ionic.native.js:15252:32)
at Object.exports.getPlugin (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8100/lib/ionic-native/ionic.native.js:12524:19)
at callCordovaPlugin (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8100/lib/ionic-native/ionic.native.js:12602:34)
at http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8100/lib/ionic-native/ionic.native.js:12651:24
at http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8100/lib/ionic-native/ionic.native.js:12635:17
at Q (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29396:5)
at getPromise (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8100/lib/ionic-native/ionic.native.js:12634:20)
at wrapPromise (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8100/lib/ionic-native/ionic.native.js:12650:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8100/lib/ionic-native/ionic.native.js:12817:20)
at Object.value [as getItem] (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8100/lib/ionic-native/ionic.native.js:12868:61) {}
```

I checked the Ionic Native (v2.9.0) code in question and found where the exception was thrown: line 15252, `for (var i = 0, path = path.split('.'), len = path.length; i < len; i++) {`:

```
{"./plugin":78}],105:[function(require,module,exports){
"use strict";
function get(obj, path) {
for (var i = 0, path = path.split('.'), len = path.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (!obj) {
        return null;
    }
    obj = obj[path[i]];
}
return obj;
}
exports.get = get;
;
```

So it seems that `path` is undefined in this `get()` function, which seems to be a helper function used in getting the Cordova plugin. I have `cordova-plugin-nativestorage` installed for Android as well as for iOS, so why it can't find `path` is beyond me.

Does anyone know what the issue here could be?

Just for fun, the output of `ionic info`:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 

local packages:

    Cordova Platforms : android 6.2.3 browser 5.0.1 ios 4.4.0 osx 4.0.1
    Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.2

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
    ios-sim    : 5.0.13 
    Node       : v7.2.0
    npm        : 2.15.12 
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b 

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Comment: Could you show code how you store and get data?

Comment: Try it  change path.split('.') to path.replace(/^file:\/\//, '').split('.')

Comment: I have added an example of how ionic-native storage works. I don't think it would be very smart for me to change core framework files.